# Customer support marquee scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Instead of using marquee, how can I roll up my customer's support ideas/comments section in my div block ?

```
<div></div>
```

I don't know what to do with this, any help please ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://bit.ly/PlvaO1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is mutch examples on http://www.htmlmarquee.com/javascript.html
And moor explanations than would fit on this page.

Hope this helps (to get some ideas)!

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
<style>
.parent { overflow: hidden; }
.child { position: parent; x: 0px; }
<style>
<div class=parent>
 <div class=child>
 </div>
</div>
```

And use javascript or css3 animation for changing attribute x.

For example css3 animation is used on this page:
http://letnyayashkola.org
http://letnyayashkola.org/static/slideshow.css

Answer (score 0):

1. Using "marquee" tag in HTMl .if this text is simple
2. Using simplyScroll plugin in Jquery. Marqueee is not smooth with complex innerHTML. `http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/`
   This plugin will make scroll smoothly